# Set duplicate values to NULL on certain conditions

Tags: sql, sqlite, duplicates

I have a fairly large SQL database (currently SQLite3) with a single relation:

```
CREATE TABLE sometable (
    `name` TEXT,
    `position` INTEGER
);
```

Due to the nature of the data, there are no primary keys or constraints, only non-unique indices on the `name` and `position` columns. Now I need to set the `name` column to `NULL` where names are duplicates but positions are not. Duplicate `(name,position)` pairs are okay and shall not be changed.

Before:

```
name | position
-----+---------
a    | 5
a    | 5
b    | 7
b    | 8
c    | 6
c    | 7
c    | 7
d    | 6
```

After:

```
name | position
-----+---------
a    | 5
a    | 5
NULL | 6
NULL | 7
NULL | 6
NULL | 7
NULL | 8
d    | 6
```

The only rows that I may keep are those where there are no ambiguities in the name/position association. Duplicate name/position pairs must be kept, though, as long as that name is not associated with another position.

I can't find a suitable SQL statement to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try an update which uses a correlated subquery to check if a given name should be replaced by `NULL`.  The subquery below aggregates by name and then checks if there be more than one position.  If so, then that name would be a candidate for the update.

```
UPDATE sometable
SET name = NULL
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sometable t2
              WHERE sometable.name = t2.name
              GROUP BY name
              HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT position) > 1);
```

Comment: SQLite3 seems to have problems with table aliases in `UPDATE` clauses, so your example yields a syntax error. I haven't thought of `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT position)`, very good idea. Thank you

Comment: Thanks, submitting the query worked now. I'll check in a few hours if that worked out. The execution will take some time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `union all` with `not exists/exists` :

```
select t.name, t.position 
from table t
where not exists (select 1 from table t1 where t1.name = t.name and t.position <> t1.position)
union all
select null, t.position 
from table t
where exists (select 1 from table t1 where t1.name = t.name and t.position <> t1.position);
```

So, the `update` version would be :

```
update table t
     set t.name = null
where exists (select 1 from table t1 where t1.name = t.name and t1.position <> t.position);
```